# State not Defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Hey Guys I had Searched almost all the sites on google But I am not able Able to get the Solution My problem is I am not able to render Javascript Variable to EJS Page.Whenever I tried to do It throws an Error that Variable is Not Defined. But I had Already Defined It. Please Review My Code I am in Big Trouble.
Here is My Code

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const https = require("https");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const state="Search Your State";
const stateNames =[];
const tableConfirmed=[];
const tableActive=[];
const tableRecovered=[];
const tableDeceased=[];
let Name;
let confirmed;
let deaths;
let recovered;
const Name1=[];
const length1= [];
const State = [];
const vaccine1 = [];
const AgeLimit1 = [];
const Dose = [];
const Dose12 = [];
const timming = [];
const timming12 = [];
const Fees1 = [];
const Address1=[];
const Slots1 = [];
const Pincode1 =[]; 
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
var GoogleStrategy = require( 'passport-google-oauth2' ).Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');
const states =[];
const app = express();
const err = "Please Search Correct State";
const commaNumber = require("comma-number");
const { SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 } = require('constants');
const err1= "Error";

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
const action = "active"; 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(today);
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
var date = yesterday.toISOString().slice(0,10);




mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/clientDB", {useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true});

mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);



const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name : String,

  email: String,

  password: String


});

const Client = new mongoose.model("Client", clientSchema);


app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.render("First");
});


app.get("/home",function(req,res){

  const url = "https://covid19-stats-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cases?country=India";
  https.get(url, function(response){
      response.on("data",function(data){
          let covidData = JSON.parse(data);
           confirmed = commaNumber(covidData.confirmed);
           deaths = commaNumber(covidData.deaths);
           recovered =commaNumber( covidData.recovered);
          res.render("home",{confirmed1:confirmed, deaths1:deaths, recovered1:recovered,state:state,stateNames:stateNames,tableConfirmed:tableConfirmed,tableActive:tableActive,tableDeceased:tableDeceased,tableRecovered:tableRecovered,Name:Name});

      });
 
  
     
  });
  const url3="https://covid-api.com/api/reports?date="+date+"&q=India&iso=IND&region_name=India";
  https.get(url3,function(response){
    response.on("data",function(data3){
      let table = JSON.parse(data3);
      for(let i=0; i<37;i++){
        let stateName = table.data[i].region.province;
        stateNames.push(stateName);
        let tableconfirmed = commaNumber(table.data[i].confirmed);
        tableConfirmed.push(tableconfirmed);
        let tableactive =commaNumber(table.data[i].active);
        tableActive.push(tableactive);
        let tablerecovered = commaNumber(table.data[i].recovered);
        tableRecovered.push(tablerecovered);
        let tabledeceased = commaNumber(table.data[i].deaths);
        tableDeceased.push(tabledeceased);

      }
    
      
      
      
      
      

});

});
});
function clearArray(array) {
  while (array.length) {
    array.pop();
  }
}
app.post("/home", function(req,res){
  let state = req.body.search;
  
  const url1 = "https://covid-api.com/api/reports?date="+date+"&q=India&iso=IND&region_name=India&region_province="+state+"";
  
  https.get(url1, function(response){
      response.on("data",function(data1){

          let covidStateData = JSON.parse(data1);
          let confirmedState = commaNumber(covidStateData.data[0].confirmed);
          let deathsState = commaNumber(covidStateData.data[0].deaths);
          let recoveredState = commaNumber(covidStateData.data[0].recovered);

          res.render("home",{confirmed1:confirmedState, deaths1:deathsState, recovered1:recoveredState,state:state,stateNames:stateNames,tableConfirmed:tableConfirmed,tableActive:tableActive,tableDeceased:tableDeceased,tableRecovered:tableRecovered,Name:Name});

      });
    
          
          
        });
        
      });
      
      
       
  app.post("/slot",function(req,res){
    let pincode = req.body.pincode;
    let date = req.body.date;
    const url4 = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPin?pincode="+pincode+"&date="+today.getDate();
    https.get(url4,function(response){
      response.on("data",function(data4){
        let pincodeData = JSON.parse(data4);

        for(var i=0; i<pincodeData.sessions.length;i++ ){
          let State1 = pincodeData.sessions[i].state_name;
          let length = pincodeData.sessions.length;
          let name = pincodeData.sessions[i].name;
          let vaccine = pincodeData.sessions[i].vaccine;
          let AgeLimit = pincodeData.sessions[i].min_age_limit;
          let Dose1 = pincodeData.sessions[i].available_capacity_dose1;
          let Dose2 = pincodeData.sessions[i].available_capacity_dose2;
          let timming1 = pincodeData.sessions[i].from;
          let timming2 = pincodeData.sessions[i].to;
          let Fees = pincodeData.sessions[i].fee_type;
          let Address = pincodeData.sessions[i].address;
          let slots = pincodeData.sessions[i].slots;
          let pincode2 = pincodeData.sessions[i].pincode;
          Name1.push(name);
          State.push(State1);
          length1.push(length); 
          vaccine1.push(vaccine);
          AgeLimit1.push(AgeLimit);
          Dose.push(Dose1);
          Dose12.push(Dose2);
          timming.push(timming1);
          timming12.push(timming2);
          Fees1.push(Fees);
          Address1.push(Address);
          Slots1.push(slots);
          Pincode1.push(pincode2);

        }
        res.render("slot",{Name:Name,State:State,Name1:Name1,length1:length1,vaccine1:vaccine1,AgeLimit1:AgeLimit1,Dose:Dose,Dose12:Dose12,timming:timming,timming12:timming12,Fees1:Fees1,Address1:Address1,Slots1:Slots1,Pincode1:Pincode1});
      });
      
    });
    
  });





  app.get("/register",function(req,res){
    res.render("register",{Name:Name});
  });

  app.get("/blog", function(req,res){
    res.render("blog",{Name:Name});
  });
app.get("/slot", function(req,res){
  res.render("slot",{Name:Name});
});
app.get("/resources", function(req,res){
  res.render("resources",{Name:Name});
});
app.get("/contact", function(req,res){
  res.render("contact",{Name:Name});
});
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
const newClient = new Client({
  name : req.body.name,
  email : req.body.username,
  password : req.body.password
});
 Name = req.body.name;
newClient.save(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    res.redirect("/home");
  }
})
});
app.post("/",function(req,res){
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  Client.findOne({email:username}, function(err,foundUser){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      if(foundUser){

        if(foundUser.password===password){
          res.redirect("/home")
        }
        Name = foundUser.name;
      }
    }
  })
})
let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3000;
}
app.listen(port,function() {
  console.log("Server started");
});`
```

Here is the EJS code

```
<%-include("partials/heading")%>


      <div class="container">
          
            <header class="intro">
    <h1>Check Slots Availability</h1>
    
    </header>
  <form method="post">
          <h3 >Enter Pincode</h3>
          
          
            <input class="pincode" type="number" maxlength="6" minlength="6" name="pincode"  >
            
            <input class="pincode" type="submit">
              
            </button>
          
          </form>
        
        <div class="box">
          <table class="table table-dark">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">State/UT</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Vaccine</th>
                <th scope="col">Age Limit</th>
                <th scope="col">Availability for Dose1</th>
                <th scope="col">Availability for Dose2</th>
                <th scope="col">Fees</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                <th scope="col">Slots</th>
                <th scope="col">Pincode</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% for(i=0;i<2;i++){ %> 
              <tr>
                <th scope="row"><%=State[i]%></th>
                <td ><%=Name1[i]%></td>
                <td ><%=vaccine1[i]%></td>
                <td ><%=AgeLimit1[i]%></td>
                <td ><%=Dose[i]%></td>
                <td ><%=Dose12[i]%></td>
                <td ><%=Fees1[i]%></td>
                <td ><%=Address1[i]%></td>
                <td ><%=Slots1[i]%></td>
                <td ><%=Pincode1[i]%></td>
             
              </tr>
              
              <% } %> 
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </dvi>
 
      </div>
  </div>
  
</div>  
    
    <%-include("partials/footer")%>
Here is The Problem Coming
```

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilI3e.png)

Comment: your not sending state in `res.render()`

Comment: I don't Understand I am Sending State in res.render()

Answer (score 0):

It seems that variable (array) like length1 and other of the same kind are not defined (at least in the code you show us). a lot of variable inside

```
res.render("slot",{Name:Name,State:State,Name1:Name1,length1:length1,vaccine1:vaccine1,AgeLimit1:AgeLimit1,Dose:Dose,Dose12:Dose12,timming:timming,timming12:timming12,Fees1:Fees1,Address1:Address1,Slots1:Slots1,Pincode1:Pincode1});
```

Comment: Actually I had  Defined Them here is My Upper Code const Name1=[];
const length1= [];
const State = [];
const vaccine1 = [];
const AgeLimit1 = [];
const Dose = [];
const Dose12 = [];
const timming = [];
const timming12 = [];
const Fees1 = [];
const Address1=[];
const Slots1 = [];
const Pincode1 =[];

Comment: @MayankDahiya Code does no help in a comment.  Edit your question instead with the info.

Comment: I had Edited My question Please Check It